# Operation not permitted "sudo ditto -v to folder /usr/bin"

Tags: terminal, macos, permission, sudo

I'm trying to copy an exec file from my downloads folder to /usr/bin/ using `sudo ditto -v sweep /usr/bin/sweep`, but the command always fails in Terminal. I even tried to manually drag and drop it but the folder only has permissions for the system account. Is there a way I can change my command to allow permissions to this folder so that I can copy the file?.

I'm using OS X 10.11.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder /usr/bin/ is (like other system folders in El Capitan) protected by SIP (System Integrity Protection).

You may either boot to Recovery Mode, disable System Integrity Protection with `csrutil disable` entered in Terminal.app and after rebooting copy the executable or use the folder /usr/local/bin instead. You may have to adjust your path in the latter case.